# Can Spark jobs be scheduled through Airflow

Tags: pyspark, airflow-scheduler

I am new to spark and need to clarify some doubts i have.

1. Can I schedule Spark Jobs through Airflow
2. My Airflow (Spark) jobs process raw csv files present in S3 bucket and then transforms into parquet format , stores it into S3 bucket and then finally stores it into Presto Hive after completely processed. End user connects to Presto and queries the data to create visualisation.

Can this processed data be stored in Hive only or Presto only so that user can connect to Presto or Hive and accordingly to perform query  on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can always [spark_submit_operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators)
to schedule and submit your spark jobs or you can use [bash operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/bash.html)
where you can use the spark-submit bash command to schedule and submit spark jobs.

to your second question, After spark created parquet files you can use spark (same spark instance) to write it to hive or presto.